# Jfif/jpeg parsing, bytes between streams

Tags: parsing, jpeg, file-format

I'm parsing an Jpeg/JFIF file and I noticed that after the SOI (0xFF D8) I parse the different "streams" starting with 0xFFXX (where XX is a hexadecimal number) until I find the EOI (0XFFD9). Now the structure of the diffrent chunks is:

```
APP0 marker     2 Bytes   
Length          2 Bytes
```

Now when I parse the a chunk I parse until i reach the length written in the 2 Bytes of the length field. After that I thought I would immediately find another Marker, followed by a length for the next chunk. According to my parser that is not always true, there might be data between the chunks. I couldn't find out what that data is, and if it is relevant to the image. Do you have any hints what this could be and how to interpret those bytes?

I'm lost and would be happy if somebody could point me in the correct direction. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I've recently noticed this too. In my case it's an APP2 chunk which is the ICC profile which doesn't contain the length of the chunk.

In fact so far as I can see the length of the chunk needn't be the first 2 bytes (though it usually is).

In JFIF all 0xFF bytes are replaced with 0xFF 0x00 in the data section, so it should just be  a matter of calculating the length from that. I just read until I hit another header, however I've noticed that sometimes (again in the ICC profile) there are byte sequences which don't make sense such as 0xFF 0x6D, so I may still be missing something.